# Passing a struct to tui::widgets::ListItem rather than a string and show the struct item in list

Tags: rust, tui

i have this rust tui which pass a list of song title's into a tui.rs crate to show the list in terminal user interface. here which i do is recursively checking the available `.mp3` files and adding the files metadata to a struct which is `SongStruct` so when i need to show the titles of of the songs i had to iter the vec of `SongStruct`  and add the `SongStruct.title` to a vec and add to `ListItem` in tui.rs. if the user click the selected item it only selected the give string which is `SongStruct.title` so rather than passing a string of text i need to pass the whole struct and show the selected `SongStruct.title`. is there any way to pass the whole struct and show the title and when user select an item get the struct details and call a function. here a below my tui code and struct

```
pub struct SongStruct {
    pub title: String,
    pub artist: String,
    pub file_path: String,
}


use std::{
    io,
    thread,
    time::Duration
};

use tui::{
    backend::CrosstermBackend,
    Terminal,
    widgets::{Widget,Block,Borders,List,ListItem},
    layout::{Layout,Direction,Constraint,Alignment},
    style::{Style,Color,Modifier}
};


use crossterm::{
    terminal::{enable_raw_mode,disable_raw_mode,EnterAlternateScreen,LeaveAlternateScreen},
    execute
};


use tui::text::{Span, Spans};

use crate::audio::Song::SongStruct;

pub fn ui(songList: Vec<SongStruct>)->Result<(),io::Error>{

    enable_raw_mode().expect("couldn't enable raw mode");
    let mut stdout = io::stdout();
    execute!(stdout, EnterAlternateScreen)?;
    let backend = CrosstermBackend::new(stdout);
    let mut terminal = Terminal::new(backend)?;

    terminal.draw(|rect|{
        let size = rect.size();
        let chunks = Layout::default()
            .direction(Direction::Vertical)
            .margin(1)
            .constraints(
                [
                    Constraint::Percentage(30),
                    Constraint::Percentage(70)
                ].as_ref()
            )
            .split(rect.size());
        let block = Block::default().title("rust-play").borders(Borders::ALL);
        let items = [ListItem::new("Item 1"), ListItem::new("Item 2"), ListItem::new("Item 3")];
        let song_list:Vec<String> = songList.into_iter().map(|song|song.title).collect();
        let listsongs:Vec<_> = song_list.into_iter().map(ListItem::new).collect();

        let title_span = Span::styled("Title Text", Style::default().fg(Color::Red));


        let list =List::new(listsongs)
        .block(Block::default().title(title_span).title_alignment(Alignment::Center).borders(Borders::ALL))
        .style(Style::default().fg(Color::Yellow))
        .highlight_style(Style::default().add_modifier(Modifier::ITALIC))
        .highlight_symbol(">>");
        rect.render_widget(block,chunks[0]);
        rect.render_widget(list,chunks[1]);
    })?;

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(5000));
    disable_raw_mode()?;
    Ok(())
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

If you look into the source, you can see that what it stores is just the string (Actually `Text` and `Style`), and it is impossible to pass anything else, including your own struct into `ItemList`.

Assuming you don't want to write your own struct, a simple workaround would be to keep a separate copy of `Vec<SongStruct>` that is passed into `ui()` as a reference.

Hope this helps.